# getting image path in jsp

Tags: image, jsp, jstl

in my project I have to upload the image and show it in user profile view . Now I am successfully storing , I have problem in displaying image. the image is stored path `D:/uploads` so my image retrieving code in jsp is,

```
<c:set var="fileanme2" value="${teacherId.getPhoto()}"></c:set>
<%
String uploadFilePath2 = "D:" + "/" + "uploads";
%>
<c:set var="shlash2" value="/"></c:set>
<c:set var="pathValue2" value="<%=uploadFilePath2%>"></c:set>
<c:set var="string4" value="${pathValue2}${shlash2}${fileanme2}" />

<img alt="Image" src="${string4}" width="160" height="160"
class="img-thumbnail">
```

But image is not displaying , when I inspect the image element in browser in src attrib it showing path as `D:/uploads/img` when I hover mouse on it shows the path along with the project path how can I get the exact path for displaying image.

Comment: is there any difference in `"D:" + "/" + "uploads"` and `"D:/uploads"` ?

Answer (score 0):

no need of any string concatenation and any extra work, you can do it in one line:

```
<c:set var="filePath" value="D:/uploads/${teacherId.getPhoto()}" />
```

and solutions for your problem:

**1)** if you are going to show image from you local file system then do like:

```
<img src="file:///D|/uploads/image_name.jpg"
     width="200"
     height="200"
     alt="Image"/>
```

*Warning:* image may not be accessible when you publish your site.

---

**2)** create a servlet to handle `GET` request's of all images by passing name of image in url like:

```
@WebServlet("/ImageServlet")
public class ImageServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 10240; // 10KB.

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("getting photo...");
        String imageName = request.getParameter("imageName");
        System.out.println("imageName: "+imageName);
        //set your upload path
        File imageFile = new File("D:\\uploads\\"+imageName);
        System.out.println("file exists: "+imageFile.exists());

        // Get content type by filename.
        String contentType = getServletContext().getMimeType(imageFile.getName());

        // Init servlet response.
        response.reset();
        response.setBufferSize(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
        response.setContentType(contentType);
        response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(imageFile.length()));
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + imageFile.getName() + "\"");

        // Prepare streams.
        BufferedInputStream input = null;
        BufferedOutputStream output = null;

        try {
            // Open streams.
            input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(imageFile), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
            output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream(), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);

            // Write file contents to response.
            byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
            int length;
            while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
        } finally {
            // Gently close streams.
            close(output);
            close(input);
        }
        // Check if file is actually an image (avoid download of other files by hackers!).
        // For all content types, see: http://www.w3schools.com/media/media_mimeref.asp
        if (contentType == null || !contentType.startsWith("image")) {
            // Do your thing if the file appears not being a real image.
            // Throw an exception, or send 404, or show default/warning image, or just ignore it.
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND); // 404.
            return;
        }

    }

    // Helpers (can be refactored to public utility class) 
    private static void close(Closeable resource) {
        if (resource != null) {
            try {
                resource.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Do your thing with the exception. Print it, log it or mail it.
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then in jsp use img tag like:

```
<img alt="Image"
     src="<c:url value="/ImageServlet?imageName=${teacherId.getPhoto()}"/>" />
```

Source: [BalusC image servlet](http://balusc.blogspot.in/2007/04/imageservlet.html)

Comment: @Raghavendra 2nd also should work, and prefer 2nd solution over 1st solution.

Comment: @Raghavendra what about 2nd solution facing any problems? let me know.